# Compile Bootstrap JS with Grunt. Adjust Gruntfile.js to watch for changes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

Created a new simple Compass/Bootstrap project with Yeoman. The SCSS files are working fine & are being compiled into public/css/main.css. I can see Gruntfile.js (below) is watching for compass files but not js files. I simply want Grunt to compile the Bootstrap.js into public/js/.
Attempted to research & change the file but I am having no luck.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    config: {
        app: 'app'
    },

    connect: {
        options: {
            port: 9000,
            livereload: 35729,
            // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
            hostname: 'localhost'
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                open: true,
                base: [
                    '.tmp',
                    '<%= config.app %>/public'
                ]
            }
        },
    },
    watch: {
        options: {
            livereload: true,
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
            },
            files: [
                '<%= config.app %>/public/{,*/}*.html',
                '<%= config.app %>/public/css/{,*/}*.css',
                '<%= config.app %>/public/images/{,*/}*'
            ]
        },

        compass: {
            files: ['**/*.{scss,sass}'],
            tasks: ['compass:dev']
        },
    },
    compass: {
        dev: {
            options: {
                sassDir: ['app/src/stylesheets'],
                cssDir: ['app/public/css'],
                environment: 'development'
            }
        },
        prod: {
            options: {
                sassDir: ['app/src/stylesheets'],
                cssDir: ['app/public/css'],
                environment: 'production'
            }
        },
    }
});

// Load the plugin
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');

// Additional
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-serve');

// Default task(s).
//grunt.registerTask('default', ['connect:livereload', 'compass:dev', 'watch']);
grunt.registerTask('serve', ['connect:livereload', 'compass:dev', 'watch']);

// prod build
grunt.registerTask('prod', ['compass:prod']);
```

};

Sure this is as simple as for some Grunt gun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SCSS files are working fine because the **compass** task is compiling them to CSS.

From what I can understand, you want Grunt to compile your js files (including bootstrap.js) into your public/js directory. For this you'll have to use [grunt concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat).

First, run `npm install grunt-contrib-concat --save-dev` in your root directory.

Then update the Gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    config: {
        app: 'app'
    },

    connect: {
        options: {
            port: 9000,
            livereload: 35729,
            // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
            hostname: 'localhost'
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                open: true,
                base: [
                    '.tmp',
                    '<%= config.app %>/public'
                ]
            }
        },
    },
    // Edited: Add concat task
    concat: {
        options: {
            separator: ';',
        },
        dist: {
            src: ['app/src/javascripts/bootstrap.js'],
            dest: 'app/public/js/app.js',
        },
    },
    watch: {
        options: {
            livereload: true,
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
            },
            files: [
                '<%= config.app %>/public/{,*/}*.html',
                '<%= config.app %>/public/css/{,*/}*.css',
                '<%= config.app %>/public/images/{,*/}*'
            ]
        },
        compass: {
            files: ['**/*.{scss,sass}'],
            tasks: ['compass:dev']
        },
        // Edited: Watch js files
        js: {
            files: ['app/src/javascripts/**/*.js'],
            tasks: ['concat'],
        },
    },
    compass: {
        dev: {
            options: {
                sassDir: ['app/src/stylesheets'],
                cssDir: ['app/public/css'],
                environment: 'development'
            }
        },
        prod: {
            options: {
                sassDir: ['app/src/stylesheets'],
                cssDir: ['app/public/css'],
                environment: 'production'
            }
        },
    }
});

// Load the plugin
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
// Edited: Load grunt-contrib-concat
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');

// Default task(s).
// Edited: Add concat
grunt.registerTask('default', ['connect:livereload', 'compass:dev', 'concat', 'watch']);
// prod build
// Edited: Add concat
grunt.registerTask('prod', ['compass:prod'], 'concat');

};
```

I recommend not updating your bootstrap.js file directly. Create a new script in the same directory and add it's name to the `concat`>`dist`>`src` array.

Comment: Thanks Hardik that is working fine now. I could see the Gruntfile.js was not watching js files but I was not sure of the correct task (uglify, jshintrc etc)? 


Regarding the additional js script file in the same directory. I would use it in the same fashion as the SCSS base file where it calls in the others (partials)?


//= require ./bootstrap/affix
//= require ./bootstrap/alert
//= require ./bootstrap/button

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Hey Kerry. The `js` part in the `watch` function will watch for all changes you make in any of the files in the _app/src/javascripts/_ directory. It will then run the `concat` task in order to update the code in the concatenated **app.js** file.

You don't need to follow the SCSS fashion for partials. You can simply create a new file next to the **bootstrap.js** file, then add the file path in the `concat` task. For e.g., if your new file is called **custom.js**, update the `src[]` array in this fashion:

`src: ['app/src/javascripts/bootstrap.js', 'app/src/javascripts/custom.js']`

Comment: @Kerry7777 Glad I could help.